# Issue connecting to remote hive server via HiveTemplate

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to connect to hive server remotely with the help of spring hadoop Hive Thrift Client. I am using the default installation of hive under Cloudera QuickStart VM 5.0.0.
I am able to connect to the Hive Server when using the Hive JDBC Client and use the JdbcTemplate to perform the queries. 
But if I try to connect to the remote hive server via the HiveTemplate, the code seems to wait for something and does not respond back.
Also, the logs do not show any errors. 
I am refering to the following documents to configure my application:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/current/reference/html/hive.html

I am using the following configuration in the hive-context.xml file

```
<hive-client-factory id="hiveClientFactory" host="${hive.host}" port="${hive.port}" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"/>  
<hive-template id="hiveTemplate"/>
```

I am using the HiveTemplate as follows:

```
@Autowired
private HiveTemplate hiveTemplate;
  public List<String> getDbs() {
   System.out.println("Hive Template ="+ hiveTemplate);
      return hiveTemplate.execute(new HiveClientCallback<List<String>>() {
             public List<String> doInHive(HiveClient hiveClient) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(" ----> In execute  getDbs  "+ hiveClient);
                 return hiveClient.get_all_databases();
             }
          });
      }
```

and my JUnit code is as follows:

```
public class TestHiveDAO {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hive-context.xml");
        HiveDaoImpl hiveDao = ctx.getBean(HiveDaoImpl.class);

        @Test
        public void testScript(){
            System.out.println("Before");
            List<String> dbs = hiveDao.getDbs();
            for(String s : dbs){
             System.out.println(" ---->  Databases  "+s);
            }
            System.out.println("After");
        }
```

The output just keep waiting for something and never completes:

    `[main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@9e5e323: startup date [Tue Aug 19 16:50:33 BST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [hive-context.xml]
    [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader  - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [jdbc-context.xml]
    [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  - Loading properties file from class path resource [hive.properties]
    [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  - Loading properties file from class path resource [hadoop.properties]
    [main] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  - Loading properties file from class path resource [hive-server.properties]
    Before
    Hive Template =org.springframework.data.hadoop.hive.HiveTemplate@48b997d0
    ----> In execute  getDbs  org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveClient@282c0dbe`

Any help will be really appreciated.